# In what ways can connectionist AI be integrated with GOFAI?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, symbolic-ai, symbolic-computing, neurosymbolic-ai

In what ways can connectionist artificial intelligence (neural networks) be integrated with *Good Old-Fashioned A.I.* (*GOFAI*)? For instance, how could deep neural networks be integrated with knowledge bases or logical inference? One such example seems to be the [OpenCog + Destin integration](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/DestinOpenCog).

Answer (score 1):

A neural net with even a single hidden layer is capable of Universal function approximation - it can approximate any continuous function 'as closely as you like'.

Hence, one option would be to look for GOFAI applications that would benefit from this property - for example, in state-space search approaches where the utility of a state is not readily defined in advance, and could instead be learned.

Comment: This has actually been done, so you could edit this answer to provide a reference or link to an example of such a work.