# What are some interesting recent papers that synthesize symbolic AI with Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, papers, symbolic-ai, neurosymbolic-ai

A lot of people seem to be under the impression that combining [GOFAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence) and contemporary AI will make models more general. I'm particularly interested in reasoning through analogy or case-based reasoning.

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/146/2444) is a very similar but older question, so yours seems to be a duplicate. Am I right?

Comment: Read some of [Jacques Pitrat's books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat)