# What are knowledge graph embeddings?

Tags: reference-request, embeddings, knowledge-graph, knowledge-graph-embeddings

What are knowledge graph embeddings? How are they useful? Are there any extensive reviews on the subject to know all the details? Note that I am asking this question just to give a quick overview of the topic and why it might be interesting or useful, I am not asking for all the details, which can be given in the reference/survey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Knowledge graph embeddings (KGE)** are embeddings created in the context of a [**knowledge graph (KG)**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/32666/2444), which can be viewed as a visual/graphical representation of a knowledge base, where nodes are **entities** (e.g. "a car" or "Lewis Hamilton") and edges are **relations** between those entities (e.g. "drives"), so a (directed) connection from "Lewis Hamilton" to "a car" through the edge "drives" would represent the fact "Lewis Hamilton drives a car".

A KGE is a vector representation of an entity or relation in the KG that, hopefully, preserves the **semantics** of the entities and relations. For example, we expect the embedding of the entity "man" to be closer to the embedding of the entity "woman" than to the embedding of a "turtle". The idea of learning a lower-dimensional vector representation of objects that preserves some notion of semantics or meaning between those objects also appears in other AI subfields, like natural language processing (see e.g. [*word embeddings*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf)), or ML applied to software engineering (see [*code embeddings*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.09473.pdf)).

A KGE can be useful because a KG is most likely incomplete, so one of the tasks that you need to solve when using a KG is determining whether a fact is true or false. So, if we denote the fact as a triple $f = \langle s, r, o \rangle$, where $s$ stands for the subject, $r$ for the relation, and $o$ the object, then we want to determine whether this fact $f$ is true or false. In the context of KGEs, this is known as **triple classification**. Of course, in our KG, we don't have the fact $f$, but maybe we have the entities $s$ and $o$ but there's no edge between them that is labeled with $r$. So, given the embeddings of $s$, $r$, and $o$ (which was previously learned), we can then use a so-called **score function** to determine the likelihood of this fact. So, KGEs can be used to discover new "likely" knowledge, but it's a different approach than using deduction to derive new knowledge from a set of axioms or facts. It's an **inductive/probabilistic approach**, which has advantages (e.g. you don't need a deductive system) but also disadvantages (e.g. the fact may not actually be true even if our approach tells us that's the case).

There are many similar/related ways to learn KGEs. Just to give you an idea of how these are learned, a simple approach (**TransE**) is as follows. You learn the vectors $s$, $r$ and $o$ such that the constraint $s + r = o$ is satisfied. Of course, this constraint only makes sense if $o$ can only go with $s$ and $r$, so this approach is not realistic, as it doesn't model e.g. many-to-many relations. For this reason, people have introduced other approaches (like **RotatE** or **ConvE**), which have advantages but also disadvantages. There are also other issues that arise when learning these embeddings, like generating synthetic negative/false facts (i.e. if you have a KG, you only have known true facts, so how do you know if a fact is false? You need examples of false facts!).

The [Wikipedia page on KGEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_graph_embedding) is already quite comprehensive, but there are many other resources on the topic. For example, the survey [Knowledge Graph Embedding: A Survey of Approaches and Applications](https://persagen.com/files/misc/Wang2017Knowledge.pdf) (2017) or the (long but very useful) tutorial [Knowledge Graph Embeddings Tutorial: From Theory to Practice](https://kge-tutorial-ecai2020.github.io/) by some of the people that are currently doing research on this topic.