# What are other types of knowledge bases except entity-entric KB?

Tags: knowledge-representation, ontology, knowledge-graph, knowledge-base

I learned a term entity-centric knowledge base, then I wonder what the non entity-centric knowledge graphs are?

I googled by keys words "entity-centric knowledge base vs" and got some articles with this most related one: A comparison between Entity-Centric Knowledge Base and Knowledge Graph to Represent Semantic Relationships for Searching as Learning Situations, then I thought "Knowledge Graph to Represent Semantic Relationships" would be the answer. But I searched and [found that](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/37620/5351) knowledge graphs are just large-scale knowledge bases.

I wonder how entity-centric knowledge base, knowledge graph and knowledge base relate to each other? Maybe ontology-centric knowledge bases?